# MySQL Stored Procedure - Checking if certain conditions are met one by one; if one is not met, exit procedure and return a specific message

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to make a MySQL stored procedure that processes a book purchase and inserts records into other tables about the purchase. However, these insertions can only happen if three conditions are met: the customer is in the system, the book is in the system, and there is enough quantity. 
I want to check for each condition individually, and if it passes the first condition, it moves to the next, but if it doesn't, I want it to end the procedure and return a value, and so on for each condition. If it passes all three conditions, the insertions can happen. Here's how I coded it:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE process_purchase(
    IN book_key INT,
    IN customer_key INT,
    IN quantity INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE book_inventory_key_var INT;
    DECLARE purchase_key_var INT;

    SELECT book_inventory_key
    INTO book_inventory_key_var
    FROM book_inventory
    WHERE book_key = book_key.book_inventory_key;

    SELECT purchase_key
    INTO purchase_key_var
    FROM purchases
    WHERE customer_key = customer_key.purchases;

    IF customer_key != customer_key.customers THEN
        SELECT '-1';
    ELSEIF book_key != book_key.books THEN
        SELECT '-2';
    ELSEIF quantity < quantity_on_stock(book_key) THEN
        SELECT '-3';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO purchases VALUES (customer_key, CURDATE());
        INSERT INTO purchase_items (book_inventory_key, purchase_key, quantity) VALUES (book_inventory_key_var, purchase_key_var, quantity);
        SELECT '1';
    END IF;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I compare the customer and book keys to their values in the other tables, and the quantity to the quantity_on_stock stored function I previously made. I use a chain of IF-ELSEIF to go through each condition one by one, and if all of them are passed, the insertions occur. If not, it won't go to the next condition, and will return the SELECT message, correct? The procedure runs without errors, but I am unsure if this is the correct method, or if there's a better way of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

Checking sequentially is subject to race conditions. Breaking this paradigm is key to moving from a procedural to SQL based method. Use the database features of to obtain consistency rather than procedural code.

`purchase_items` should have foreign key constraints to `book_key` and `customer_key` tables. If an insert generates a FK exception then one of these apply depending on the error. [DECLARE HANDLER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html) will help catch these errors.

For the quantity:

```
 INSERT INTO purchase_items (book_inventory_key, purchase_key, quantity)
 SELECT book_key, purchase_key, quantity
 FROM books WHERE book_key = book.id AND book.available >= quantity
```

If there are no [ROW_COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) for this, then there wasn't sufficient quantity.

You will also need to reduce the amount of books available in the same SQL transaction.

If you don't have to do this in a STORED PROCEDURE, don't. A lot of the constructs here are easier in application code. If this is an assignment, where store procedures are require to get extra marks, get through it, and never write a stored procedure again.